# unable to open Cube language model params for hindi Language in tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract, hindi, language-model

Tesseract unable to read cube language model.
`tesseract 1.png output.txt -l hin`
After above command execution following error occur.

```
Cube ERROR (CubeRecoContext::Load): unable to read cube language model params from /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/hin.cube.lm
Cube ERROR (CubeRecoContext::Create): unable to init CubeRecoContext object
init_cube_objects(false, &tessdata_manager):Error:Assert failed:in file tessedit.cpp, line 207
Segmentation fault
```

Where I get **hin.cube.lm** file and how to deal with that file?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, Have you found any solutions? I just copied github hin files from tessedata to my local folder.

Comment: @mridul I also do same thing. copy files to local folder, its work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this error by installing the correct versions of the below files:

- hin.cube.bigrams
- hin.cube.fold
- hin.cube.lm
- hin.cube.nn
- hin.cube.params
- hin.cube.word-freq
- hin.tesseract_cube.nn

Along with the correct versions of the Hindi AND English training data.

All above files are available at:
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files#data-files-for-version-304305

I put these files under: /usr/local/share/tessdata

This is on CentOS 7.2

Comment: where did you find those file ?? i managed to find only traineddata on github :(

Comment: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files#cube-data-files-for-version-304305

Comment: can you tell me where can i find cube data for other language like japan ?? i have found this one and thanks for your reply